# How to get sum of values (separated by types) and groupped by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table of user current values which contains a reference to the user and the type

**user_type_values**

| id | owner_id | type_id | current_value | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-23 13:36:30 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 2021-07-24 12:36:30 | 2021-07-25 12:36:40 |

Also I have a history of this table

**user_type_values_history**

| id | user_type_value_id | change_date | moment_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-07-23 12:36:30 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-07-23 13:36:30 | 10 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021-07-24 12:36:30 | 6 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021-07-24 12:36:30 | 10 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-07-25 12:36:40 | 5 |

In this table, insertion occurs when user_type_values are inserted or updated.

In the output i want to get a table like this

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-22 00:00:00 | 8 |
| 2021-07-23 00:00:00 | 15 |
| 2021-07-24 00:00:00 | 25 |
| 2021-07-25 00:00:00 | 20 |

The Value is calculated by the sum of the states of all types as of the date

**UPD**:
I'm not good in English, but I try to explain.

Let's go back to the past to 2021-07-22 00:00:00
In user_type_values was only 2 records

| id | owner_id | type_id | current_value | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 |

and to this date sum of currentValues was 8

Okay, go to 1 day forward to 2021-07-23 00:00:00
In this date in a user_type_values  was also 2 records

| id | owner_id | type_id | current_value | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 2021-07-22 12:36:30 | 2021-07-23 13:36:30 |

but sum of currentValues was already 15

and by this way it should work

Comment: You have different types in the second table but only one type in the first table.  There is only one corresponding type -- I just don't understand how you are filtering the data to get the rows in the second table.  And if the sum is cumulative and the values are positive, how does it ever decrease?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I sealed up. About filtering: When in a first table occurs isertions of updates in a second table added values of updated data from the first

Comment: What's the output expected? The sum of `moment_value` data coming from `user_type_values_history` per day?

Comment: @Ftisiot I edited the post to add context and logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to check the status of the `user_type_values` table at each day and sum the `current_value`.

This can be obtained by parsing the `user_type_values_history` table and calculating the **last** `moment_value` per `day` and `user_type_value_id`.

If so I recreated your `user_type_history` dataset with the following

```
create table user_type_history (id int, user_type_value_id int, change_date timestamp, moment_value int);

insert into user_type_history values (1,    1,  '2021-07-22 12:36:30',  5);
insert into user_type_history values (2,    2,  '2021-07-22 12:36:30',  3);
insert into user_type_history values (3,    2,  '2021-07-23 12:36:30',  7);
insert into user_type_history values (4,    2,  '2021-07-23 13:36:30',  10);
insert into user_type_history values (5,    3,  '2021-07-24 12:36:30',  6);
insert into user_type_history values (6,    3,  '2021-07-24 12:36:30',  10);
insert into user_type_history values (7,    3,  '2021-07-25 12:36:40',  5);
```

The following query (based on this [post](https://hakibenita.com/sql-group-by-first-last-value)) calculates the latest value per day and `user_type_value_id`.

```
select 
        date_trunc('day',change_date) dt, 
        user_type_value_id, 
        (MAX(ARRAY[id, moment_value]))[2] as val 
    from user_type_history
    group by 
        date_trunc('day',change_date), 
        user_type_value_id 
    order by 1,2
```

The result is

```
         dt          | user_type_value_id | val 
---------------------+--------------------+-----
 2021-07-22 00:00:00 |                  1 |   5
 2021-07-22 00:00:00 |                  2 |   3
 2021-07-23 00:00:00 |                  2 |  10
 2021-07-24 00:00:00 |                  3 |  10
 2021-07-25 00:00:00 |                  3 |   5
```

Then it's a matter of aggregating the result per day...the complete query is

```
with tot_per_day_per_user_type as(
    select 
        date_trunc('day',change_date) dt, 
        user_type_value_id, 
        (MAX(ARRAY[id, moment_value]))[2] as val 
    from user_type_history
    group by 
        date_trunc('day',change_date), 
        user_type_value_id 
    order by 1,2
    )
select 
    dt, 
    sum(val) val
from tot_per_day_per_user_type
group by dt
order by 1
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the answer, but it is not correct. In the output i want to sum all of types to this date. I don not know what to do. It is not a cumulative sum. It is sum of user_type_values that was on this date